# Error in bibliography. how to remove double heading of references

Tags: bibliographies

I am using the `article` class. `ref.bib` is the file that contains the bibliographic entries.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}

\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibliography{ref}
\end{thebibliography}
```

When I generate the Pdf I get two headings of "References". How can I get rid of at least one of the headings ?

[image: Image of pdf is attached]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Delete the instructions `\begin{thebibliography}{}` and `\end{thebibliography}`, which aren't needed when creating the bibliography with a software tool such as BibTeX.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the solution has already been provided in the comments.

Comment: Dear Sebastiano,  Thanx alot

Answer (score 1):

Delete the instructions `\begin{thebibliography}{}` and `\end{thebibliography}`, use only `\bibliography{ref}`.

Comment: thanx, a lot for your solution.it really works and solved my problem